# Should RNN attention weights over variable length sequences be re-normalized to "mask" the effects of zero-padding?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

To be clear, I am referring to "self-attention" of the type described in [Hierarchical Attention Networks for Document Classification](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./hovy/papers/16HLT-hierarchical-attention-networks.pdf) and implemented many places, for example: [here](https://github.com/ilivans/tf-rnn-attention/blob/master/attention.py).  I am **not** referring to the seq2seq type of attention used in encoder-decoder models (i.e. Bahdanau), although my question might apply to that as well... I am just not as familiar with it.

Self-attention basically just computes a weighted average of RNN hidden states (a generalization of mean-pooling, i.e. un-weighted average).  When there are variable length sequences in the same batch, they will typically be zero-padded to the length of the longest sequence in the batch (if using dynamic RNN).  When the attention weights are computed for each sequence, the final step is a softmax, so the attention weights sum to 1.

*However*, in every attention implementation I have seen, there is no care taken to mask out, or otherwise cancel, the effects of the zero-padding on the attention weights.  This seems wrong to me, but I fear maybe I am missing something since nobody else seems bothered by this.

For example, consider a sequence of length 2, zero-padded to length 5.  Ultimately this leads to the attention weights being computed as the softmax of a similarly 0-padded vector, e.g.:

> weights = softmax([0.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0]) = [0.20, 0.23, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19]

and because exp(0)=1, the zero-padding in effect "waters down" the attention weights.  This can be easily fixed, after the softmax operation, by multiplying the weights with a binary mask, i.e.

> mask = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

and then re-normalizing the weights to sum to 1. Which would result in:

> weights = [0.48, 0.52, 0, 0, 0]

When I do this, I almost *always* see a performance boost (in the accuracy of my models - I am doing document classification/regression).  So why does nobody do this?

For a while I considered that maybe all that matters is the *relative* values of the attention weights (i.e., ratios), since the gradient doesn't pass through the zero-padding anyway.  But then why would we use softmax at all, as opposed to just exp(.), if normalization doesn't matter?  (plus, that wouldn't explain the performance boost...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! I believe your concern is valid and zero attention scores for the padded encoder outputs *do affect* the attention. However, there are few aspects that you have to keep in mind:

- There are different score functions, the one in [tf-rnn-attention](https://github.com/ilivans/tf-rnn-attention/blob/master/attention.py) uses simple linear + tanh + linear transformation. But even this score function *can* learn to output negative scores. If you look at the code and imagine `inputs` consists of zeros, vector `v` is not necessarily zero due to bias and the dot product with `u_omega` can boost it further to low negative numbers (in other words, plain simple NN with a non-linearity can make both positive and negative predictions). Low negative scores don't water down the high scores in softmax.
- Due to bucketing technique, the sequences within a bucket *usually* have roughly the same length, so it's unlikely to have half of the input sequence padded with zeros. Of course, it doesn't fix anything, it just means that in real applications negative effect from the padding is naturally limited.
- You mentioned it in the end, but I'd like to stress it too: the final attended output is the *weighted sum* of encoder outputs, i.e. *relative* values actually matter. Take your own example and compute the weighted sum in this case:

  - the first one is `0.2 * o1 + 0.23 * o2` (the rest is zero)
  - the second one is `0.48 * o1 + 0.52 * o2` (the rest is zero too)

  Yes, the magnitude of the second vector is two times bigger and it isn't a critical issue, because it goes then to the linear layer. But relative attention on `o2` is just 7% higher, than it would have been with masking.

  What this means is that even if the attention weights won't do a good job in learning to ignore zero outputs, the end effect on the output vector is still good enough for the decoder to take the right outputs into account, in this case to concentrate on `o2`.

Hope this convinces you that re-normalization isn't that critical, though probably will speed-up learning if actually applied.

Answer (score 4):

[BERT implementation](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/modeling.py) applies a padding mask for calculating attention score.
Adds 0 to the non-padding attention score and adds -10000 to padding attention scores. the e^-10000 is very small w.r.t to other attention score values.

```
attention_score = [0.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0]
mask = [0, 0, -10000, -10000] # -10000 is a large negative value 
attention_score += mask
weights = softmax(attention_score)
```